# PMOS Cascode (Virtuoso)

Tags: mosfet, pmos, cadence, cascode

I have been given an assignment in which I have to implement a common source PMOS cascode (2 PMOS's above Vout, with upper one having the input voltage, and 2 NMOS's below Vout) using Cadence Virtuoso. Can somebody please point me in the right direction and give me some indications as to where I should start? The specs are as follows and the input frequency is 1KHz[image: specs of cascoded PMOS]

Comment: start what? learning what a PMOS is? what common source is? how to design a cascode? what the NMOS are for? WAY too broad at the moment, probably the only viable answer would be "start by reading Horowitz & Hill, chapters 1 to about 5 or 6."

Comment: How to go on with the cascoding and what parameters I need, exactly

Comment: *How to go on with the cascoding* That is also explained in many books about analog circuit design. We're not here to repeat what is in those books. Go study cascodes and how they work. Then build one in Cadence and start simulating.